# Find words that appear only once

Tags: python

I am retrieving only unique words in a file, here is what I have so far, however is there a better way to achieve this in python in terms of big O notation? Right now this is n squared

```
def retHapax():
    file = open("myfile.txt")
    myMap = {}
    uniqueMap = {}
    for i in file:
        myList = i.split(' ')
        for j in myList:
            j = j.rstrip()
            if j in myMap:
                del uniqueMap[j]
            else:
                myMap[j] = 1
                uniqueMap[j] = 1
    file.close()
    print uniqueMap
```

Comment: do you mean unique as in they only appear once?

Comment: yes, words only appearing once

Comment: That's O(n), not O(n^2), since Python dict / set lookup is O(1), unless you have weird keys that cause _lots_ of hash collisions. Your code would be slightly more memory efficient if it used sets instead of dicts, but they're both implemented as hash tables under the hood. However, using a Counter is a better plan: it makes the code easier to read, and you delegate more of the work to code that runs at C speed, rather than doing that Python-speed if test.

Comment: FWIW, allocating & `del`ing entries in `uniqueMap` is not exactly speed-friendly. Also, consider what your code does if it encounters a word that occurs 3 or more times in the source file. When it gets seen the 3rd & subsequent times, you attempt to `del` it from `uniqueMap`, but it's already been deleted... Oops!

Comment: @PM2Ring In principle, `Counter()` could run at C speed. It is currently implemented in Python, though (in CPython 2.7, at least).

Comment: @PM2Ring Sorry, I take this back: the class is written in Python (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a5d50a207eed409db171bab7ca03bea9c3a61232/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L422), but a C helper function is used, normally (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/58314579ece3b16341785486092f5f0222e0fd0d/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c#L2093).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to get unique words in a file.using `Counter`

```
from collections import Counter
with open("myfile.txt") as input_file:
    word_counts = Counter(word for line in input_file for word in line.split())
>>> [word for (word, count) in word_counts.iteritems() if count==1]
-> list of unique words (words that appear exactly once)
```

Comment: @godzilla it cant, because `set` removes duplicates.But it cannot find which elements is `unique`.

Comment: `set(f)` would also just create a set of unique lines.

Comment: I changed the variable names so that the code is more legible, and I used a form that uses less memory (the file is closed and not read completely into memory first anymore).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to find all unique words and consider `foo` the same as `foo.` and you need to strip punctuation.

```
from collections import Counter
from string import punctuation

with open("myfile.txt") as f:
    word_counts = Counter(word.strip(punctuation) for line in f for word in line.split())

print([word for word, count in word_counts.iteritems() if count == 1])
```

If you want to ignore case you also need to use `line.lower()`. If you want to accurately get unique word then there is more involved than just splitting the lines on whitespace.

Comment: It's more efficient to use `print([k for k,v in c.items() if v == 1])` here instead of a `__getitem__` call...

Comment: @JonClements, yes True, just took less time to write ot the other way ;)

Comment: It is even more efficient to use `.iteritems()`—much smaller memory footprint.

Comment: He's using Python 2 (print statement).

Comment: This is a good solution, so I fixed the `rstrip()` so that "Hello" is handled, and I also gave variables meaningful names so that the code is easier to read. It's mostly the same as itzmeontv's though, as far as solving the problem solved in the original question.

Comment: Your dict solution does not work. Try an odd number of identical words. It's also probably slower than `Counter`, which is meant to count (and therefore detect duplicates in a correct way).

Comment: I also removed the useless `word_counts = Counter()`.

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with the `collections.Counter` approach, but if you *only* wanted to use `set`s, then you could do so by:

```
with open('myfile.txt') as input_file:
    all_words = set()
    dupes = set() 
    for word in (word for line in input_file for word in line.split()):
        if word in all_words:
            dupes.add(word)
        all_words.add(word)

    unique = all_words - dupes
```

Given an input of:

```
one two three
two three four
four five six
```

Has an output of:

```
{'five', 'one', 'six'}
```

Comment: This is the most effcient solution

Comment: @Padraic unless you've done some `timeit`s - I doubt it is... the Counter approach is more intuitive and more efficient

Comment: I have just timed it, 1.16ms vs 1.68ms on 2000 words

Comment: lol I was double checking, will run it on some really large input later.

Comment: @Padraic umm... what about say 1 million?

Comment: Ok, scratch that, your solution sucks :P

Comment: @Padraic yup - memory usage is going to go way above just incrementing an int :)

Comment: For small N - not having the overhead of a K/V pair will be better, but after a certain threshold, storing all dupes and removing from all_words is going to be a real *beep*

Comment: It was actually worse than needing larger input, I was comparing the wrong code :D, I could not understand how it was faster, now I know why I couldn't!

Comment: It's still an O(n) solution, so it's not too bad. But indeed, `Counter()` is arguably the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You could slightly modify your logic and move it from unique on second occurrence (example using sets instead of dicts):

```
words = set()
unique_words = set()
for w in (word.strip() for line in f for word in line.split(' ')):
    if w in words:
        continue
    if w in unique_words:
        unique_words.remove(w)
        words.add(w)
    else:
        unique_words.add(w)
print(unique_words)
```

Comment: I think the OP is trying to find worlds that occur only once in the file.

Comment: There is no need for `word.strip()` if you simply do `line.split()` (with no argument).

Comment: indeed, I was just trying to follow the OP code [just noticed I should have used rstrip()]